# Replace "via Graph API Explorer" label by my application name

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, post

I am quite new in Facebook application development. I was playing the all day with "how to post a message on the wall of a page?". I finally succeeded but each message got "via Graph API Explorer". I tried to find how to change it to my application name without success. I tried to see if I could force the value of application in the api command but it did not take it into account. Maybe I miss something :( If someone can help, that would be great!

---

I am still quite confused. Let me try to explain what I want to do: I would like to automatically publish on a page (as the page) some event that are defined on a website (in a kind of agenda). What I miss, I think, is how everything is working together on Facebook side:
1. the login process: as the application will run in a cron, this should not display a login dialog box.
2. the access token: application or page one?
3. the permissions: from my understanding, I need manage_pages (and publish_stream) but not clear how this should be set.

Thx for any clarification and maybe a clear example :o)

Comment: Er, are you posting the message to the user's wall using the Graph API Explorer?  Or from within your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I have finally found the way to do it. I needed a page access code and not an application access code. The token must be generated outside the application as a long live one.

- Get a code using:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri={my_url}&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream`

app_id is your application ID
my_url is your application URL
scope is the permission you want to be granted

In the redirected URL, you will have a code parameter. Copy it.

- Generate the user access code using:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri={my_url}&client_secret={app_secret}&code={code}`

app_secret is your application secret key
code is the code from step 1

You will get as output the user access token. This one is a short live one.

- convert the short live to a long live user access token using:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&fb_exchange_token={short live access token}`

Replace the "short live access token" by the one you got on step 2
You will get as output the infinite user access token.

- Get the page access token (this one will be infinite access token as
  the user access token is now an infinite access token too):

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={infinite user access token}`

Replace the "infinite user access token" with the value you got on step 3.

This command will list all the pages you administer. The output contains the page access token you need in field "access_token". You can so use this token in any API command in your application.

The best of the best is to do all those steps via a server side program (PHP for me) as the application secret key should remain "secret".

Answer (score 2):

You need the user to authorise your own App using one of the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) flows and grant you one of the publishing [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) -

If it says 'via Graph API Explorer' on the posts your app makes you're using the access token you retrieved when you were testing the API using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) tool, not one produced by your own app

Comment: My application is publishing on a page using the access token I retrieved using the me/accounts API command (executed in Graph API explorer indeed). This command lists all the pages I am administrator. How should I process?

Comment: By retrieving the page access token using an access token you retrieved with your own app - see the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) documentation

Comment: As I want to publish to a page but as my application ( not as me), what I need is an application access token? Is this correct?

Comment: humm how can I set the right permission to my app in order for it to publish on a page? I see that permissions should be manage_pages & publish_stream but I can not find the way to do it.