# How to remove Posted Via Graph Api when posting on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I am posting to Facebook using c#

```
private static void PostToPage(string message)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient("My Little Pony Facebook token is Magic");
            var argList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            argList["message"] = message;
            fb.Post("feed", argList);
        }
```

But I get this `Posted via Graph Api Explorer` on the face book wall (check this [IMAGELINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92n3F.jpg)). Any way I can customise this to make it more personal like `Posted By user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this SO Discussion:
[Replace "via Graph API Explorer" label by my application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979009/replace-via-graph-api-explorer-label-by-my-application-name)

> If it says 'via Graph API Explorer' on the posts your app makes you're
>   using the access token you retrieved when you were testing the API
>   using the Graph API Explorer tool, not one produced by your own app